# Can a HTML5 link foreground the (non-_blank) target context?

Tags: html

```
<a href="foo.html" target="foobar">foo</a>
<a href="bar.html" target="foobar">bar</a>
```

If I click the first of these links, it opens in a new tab. If I go back and click the second link it opens in that same new tab, but in the background.

I would like to advise the browser to open the `foobar` browsing context in the foreground instead of the background, i.e. focus the tab regardless of whether it was created or reused.

Judging by [the MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target) this doesn't seem to be doable in pure HTML5. Is it? If it is, is it good practice, or should I instead use `target="_blank"` if I want to focus a new tab?